# Oracle 01033 Initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: authentication, oracle10g

I've been receiving Oracle 01033 Initialization or shutdown in progress error when I try to log in to Oracle database using TOAD. When I try in SQLPlus I can connect to the database. I tried "alter database open" command and I got the following errors:

```
 ORA-01122: database file 7 failed verification check
 ORA-01110: data file 7: 'C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\STAJ.DBF'
 ORA-01203: wrong incarnation of this file - wrong creation SCN
```

I looked up the answers for the same problem in stackoverflow but they did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database needs to be recovered.  The file fails the verification checks and so the database won't open, hence the message in TOAD.  SQLPlus works (locally at least) because you use that to start and stop the database, hence why you don't get the message when you use that otherwise you wouldn't be able to do anything.  Get your DBA to perform a recovery (via RMAN or the method of their choice).